# How to add an object created elsewhere as dagger dependency?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I wonder how to add an object created elsewhere as dependency to be provided by dagger module.

For example, I am using data binding. `MainActivity::onCreate()` gets `ActivityMainBinding` object after layout is inflated like this:

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = 
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
```

Now, how can I make this binding object available elsewhere through dagger module?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it to the module's constructor and return it (or something derived from it) from a `@Provides` method.  For example:

```
@AppScope
@Module
public class AppModule {
    private final Context mContext;

    public AppModule(@NonNull final Context context) {
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Provides
    @AppScope
    Context provideApplicationContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    // more @Provides methods...
}
```

If you have activity-scoped dependencies, the activity can create a submodule using this same approach.  Fragments can then get the activity's Dagger component and inject themselves.

Comment: Agreed that's the right approach for context. However, in the example I gave in the question, it is not a context. Module is already instantiated by application (since activity itself has dependencies injected from module). I cannot inflate the layout earlier to make it available during module instantiation.

Comment: Interesting. I will check if I can do this in my case. Example code for the submodule approach would make your answer superior.

Comment: In the above code, `provideApplicationContext` should never, ever be scoped.  A scope annotation is a signal that the framework needs to memoize the result, but the method will just return the same instance no matter what.  Thus, no need to memoize.

Comment: Also, applying `@AppScope` to a `@Module` probably doesn't do what you think it does here.  Putting scope on a class means that if you ever inject that class, that scope will be applied.  Obviously, you're not going to inject a module.  That should be removed.

Comment: @gk5885 Thanks for the tips.  Sounds like both of these things are unnecessary but harmless.

Comment: Unnecessary scoping _does_ incur a performance penalty.  It will be functionally correct, but you introduce a memory barrier and an extra object for no reason.